# different widget depending on content type

Tags: theming, forms

When two different content types shares a field, and you choose a widget for that field. Drupal 7 will show the same widget for both content types.
What i'am trying to achieve is to use a different widget for one of those content types.
Just like date_select for one and date_popup for the other one.
I don´t know how to do this... a hook in themes template? maybe a custom module?
Aproaches:
I have been digging a little bit and fouund this function:

```
function MY_MODULE_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {
}
```

Maybe with a few conditionals like, if $form_id is... and content type is...
if $context[instance][widget][type] = date_popup;

Thanks a lot.

Edit:
I have tried this code into a cuestom module but it doesen´t work, don´t know why.

```
    function ftte_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
if ($form_id == 'informals_node_form') {
    $form['field_tria']['#attributes']['class'][2] = field-widget-date-popup;
     }
}
```

Comment: Is this for Drupal 7?

Comment: Sorry i forgot, yes it is.

Comment: Or an alternative would be to use hook_form_alter  and alter the node add and edit form and change the field type there.